# Email Service implementation - Inline Images appear as 'Inline Image 1'

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, email2case

I have an Email Service set up to implement the Messaging.InboundEmailHandler interface.

For Cases created through my Email Service, the images in the sent email appears as 'inline image 1' and converted to attachments on the Case:[image]

I suspect that the default Email-To-Case mechanism has a special treatment to show the images in the Case Feed (as introduced in Summer 15' - https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_e2c_html_email_feed_items.htm), and wonder if there is any  workaround to incorporate the same functionality for the Email services implementation.

Looking online, I bumped into the '[Handling Inline Images in Salesforce Inbound Email](http://simplyforce.blogspot.co.il/2014/08/handling-inline-images-in-salesforce.html)' article, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Thank you.

Comment: this solved this issue
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183402/custom-email-service-inline-images-appear-as-image-is-no-longer-available

Comment: This is the fix https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183402/custom-email-service-inline-images-appear-as-image-is-no-longer-available